# Database backup script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

i'm pretty new to Oracle and i'm trying to make a script that backups the database everytime it's ran from cronjob.

I've been looking on a lot of discussions online but i didn't really manage to find anything even tho i made some small steps.
What i need to do is run everything from 1 single script, wether it goes from creating the database directory backup location to running the backup itself

```
sqlplus / as SYSDBA << EOF
CREATE DIRECTORY dmpdir AS '/nfs/ora_bck/';
exit
EOF
```

It should give me some positive output but instead i get some database not mounted error which doesn't make sense because it's our production database which is up and running without any issues

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<<EOF` ( space removed from `<< EOF` ), and use UpperCase directory name `DMPDIR` with privileges granted ( `grant read, write on directory DMPDIR to <yourSchema>` ), and make sure the path `/nfs/ora_bck/` really exists.

Comment: It exists and it's mounted, tried with space and without but the output is the same, i'm now getting a different error:
Connected to an idle instance.
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Comment: @valerioooo seems you need to issue the command `SQL> startup`

Comment: it's not that, the database is up and running, i had a problem with the code which i solved, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out all i needed to add is:
export ORACLE_SID=*SID* (which you can find from ps -ef | grep pmon )
and then the remaining parts of the script.

Hopefully this will help someone who had the same issues.

Just in case anyone needs the scripts to:

command.sh

```
export ORACLE_SID=SID
sqlplus / as SYSDBA <<EOF
CREATE DIRECTORY fulldp_dir AS '/mnt/nfs/backup_ora/';
exit
EOF
```

backup.sh

```
export ORACLE_SID=SID
expdp \"/ as sysdba\" directory=fulldp_dir full=y dumpfile=full_exp.dmp logfile=full_exp.log
```

Comment: It's not just ORACLE_SID; you might need a few others like LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_HOME. Fortunately on UNIX/Linux environments Oracle provide a script called `oraenv` . When script you would do 
`export ORAENV_ASK=NO; 
export ORACLE_SID=SID;
 . oraenv;
 export ORAENV_ASK=YES`.